# Creating a complex aligned equation with blockarray

Tags: math-mode, equations, vertical-alignment, alignment, arrays

I am trying to create the following equation. The main challenge is vertically aligning the `=` sign with curly brace and aligning the bottom rows below the horizontal line.

## Desired Figure

[image]

## Current Attempt

[image]

```
\begin{align}
\begin{blockarray}{llll}
\begin{block}{(llll)}
1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
\cline{1-4}
\end{block}
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{blockarray}
=
\begin{blockarray}{llll}
\begin{block}{\{llll}
1&0&1&1\\[5pt]
1&0&1&1\\[5pt]
1&0&1&1\\[5pt]
\cline{1-4}
\end{block}
1&0&1&1
\end{blockarray}
\end{align}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a possibility with `nicematrix`. One way to guarantee alignment in different arrays is to make them both part of the same array (or in this case, the same `NiceMatrix`).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{NiceMatrix}
\Block{3-4}{\begin{pmatrix}1&0&1&1\\0&1&1&0\end{pmatrix}\vspace{1ex}}&&&&&1&0&1&1\\
&&&&=&1&0&1&1\\
&&&&&1&0&1&1\\[1ex] \cline{1-4}\cline{6-9}
0&0&0&1&&1&0&1&1
\CodeAfter
  \SubMatrix\{{1-6}{3-9}.
\end{NiceMatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is it possible to stop the large left bracket from being so close to the horizontal line?

Comment: It is possible to use `\\[10pt] \cline{...}` in such cases.

Comment: @jII: Yes, but then you should also add `\vspace{10pt}` after `\end{pmatrix}` to keep the left array vertically aligned with the `=` sign`. I edited my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

This exploits the fact that all matrices have the same horizontal size.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,array}

\begin{document}

\[
\newcommand{\AAA}{%
  \begin{array}{@{}cccc@{}}
  1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
  0 & 1 & 1 & 0
  \end{array}%
}
\newcommand{\BBB}{%
  \begin{array}{@{}cccc@{}}
  1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
  1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
  1 & 0 & 1 & 1
  \end{array}%
}
\begin{array}{
  @{}
  c@{}           % left (
  c@{}           % matrix
  c@{}           % right )
  >{{}}c<{{}}@{} % =
  c@{}           % left {
  c@{}           % matrix
}
\left(\vphantom{\AAA}\right.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace
&\AAA&
\left.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace\vphantom{\AAA}\right)
&=&
\left\{\vphantom{\BBB}\right.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace
&\BBB
\\
&
\begin{array}{@{}cccc@{}} \\[-2ex] \hline 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{array}
&&&&
\begin{array}{@{}cccc@{}} \\[-2ex] \hline 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \end{array}
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]